# Query for sum of all and particular rows

Tags: sql-server

How can I arrive at a query for the below scenario?

**Data**:

```
Date        Product  Result  Total
15/01/2015  ABC      Pass     5 
15/01/2015  XYZ      Pass     8 
15/01/2015  MNO      Fail     2 
23/01/2015  ABC      Pass    10 
23/01/2015  XYZ      Fail     3
```

I need the result in the below format:

```
Date        Total  Pass  Fail 
15/01/2015  15     13    2 
23/01/2015  13     10    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `conditional Aggregate`

```
select Date  
       sum(Total) Total,
       SUM(case when Result  ='Pass' then Total else 0 end) Pass,
       SUM(case when Result  ='Fail' then Total else 0 end) Fail
From yourtable
Group by Date
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `PIVOT` . [**FIDDLER DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ec47/1)

```
SELECT Date, 
      sum(pass) + sum(fail) AS Total, 
      sum(pass) AS Pass, 
      sum(fail) AS Fail 
FROM TableName
PIVOT (SUM(Total) FOR Result in (pass, fail)) AS P
GROUP BY Date
```